# Remove a dynamically created element by looping through an array after 2 seconds in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on a component for notifications in Angular 8 app and i need to hide notifications 2 seconds after they appear.

I have notifications stored in an array and make a loop to show its items in html as shown below:

> from **notifications.component.ts** file:

```
export class NotificationsComponent {

  notifications: Notifications[] = this.notifSer.notifications;

  constructor(private notifSer: NotificationsService) {}

}
```

> **notifications.component.html** file:

```
<ul class="notifications-container">
  <li *ngFor="let notif of notifications" [class]="notif.class">
    {{ notif.msg }}
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> from **test.component.ts** file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements {

  constructor(private notifSer: NotificationsService) {}

  // set Values to Notifications to Show Messages
  setNotif(notificationsValue: Notifications) {
    this.notifSer.setNotif(notificationsValue);
  }
}
```

> from **test.component.html** file:

```
<button (click)="setNotif({class: 'success', msg: 'hey there!'})">
  show notification
</button>
```

> from **notifications.service.ts** file:

```
export class NotificationsService {

  notifications: Notifications[] = []; // store notifications here

  setNotif(notification: Notifications): void {
    this.notifications.push(notification);
  }

}
```

What I'm asking is how to automatically remove notifications 2 seconds after they appear.
I made this solution in (**notifications.service**) file but it disappears immediately and i want to fade it out:

```
setNotif(notification: Notifications): void {
    this.notifications.push(notification);
    // Remove the notification from the notifications array after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.notifications.shift();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple StackBlitz that shows animating messages that fade in and out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkjyzg

You need to install the @angular/animations package.

Import the BrowserAnimationsModule to your module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then define the animations you wish to use in the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    // the fade-in/fade-out animation.
    trigger('simpleFadeAnimation', [

      // the "in" style determines the "resting" state of the element when it is visible.
      state('in', style({opacity: 1})),

      // fade in when created. this could also be written as transition('void => *')
      transition(':enter', [
        style({opacity: 0}),
        animate(600 )
      ]),

      // fade out when destroyed. this could also be written as transition('void => *')
      transition(':leave',
        animate(600, style({opacity: 0})))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  messages = [];

  num = 1;

  add() {
    const message = 'New message ' + this.num++;
    this.messages = [...this.messages, message];
    setTimeout(() => { this.messages = this.messages.filter(m => m !== message); }, 2000);
  }
}
```

and in the template when you add an element it will fade in then fade out 2 seconds later

```
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>

<div *ngFor="let message of messages" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">{{message}}</div>
```

Here is the article I based this on https://www.kdechant.com/blog/angular-animations-fade-in-and-fade-out